# How can I control which apps are able to use the data connection while roaming?

Tags: sync, roaming

I am planning a trip to abroad and need to use my Android phone while roaming.

But i couldn't disable all data roaming because i need my company emails.
So i want to disable WhatsApp, Facebook, Twitter, Play Store and etc; except Exchange.

Is there any way to achieve this?  My device is rooted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Block apps from accessing the Internet on Android device](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/40924/block-apps-from-accessing-the-internet-on-android-device)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Install [Avast](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.avast.android.mobilesecurity). Enter its Firewall section (requires *root access* to work) and allow/deny apps in Roaming column (Wi-Fi and Home Cell access will be untouched). Avast's firewall provides two modes: Block Selected and Allow Selected. Choose any as per your requirement.

Use [My Data Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobidia.android.mdm) if you want to track data usage of individual apps. It has dedicated Roaming section. It can help you in creating firewall rules or lowering data usage of important apps.

Answer (score 11):

Give a try to Onavo Count - it can block certain apps to use only WiFi, cap data usage, provide alerts on data hogging apps, has widgets and more.

Link: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.onavo.android.onavoid

Overall, it's a very handy app for data management. It also comes with a companion app Onavo Extend to save on data usage: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.onavo.android.onavoics

I would also suggest to keep data turned off as a pre-caution, and turning it on periodically - even if you use Onavo. Settings > Wireless & Networks > Mobile Networks and tick off the "Data roaming" checkbox.

Enjoy your trip!

Comment: How Onavo Count can block apps to use only WiFi? I can't see such an option in the app.

Comment: Onavo Count is a Spyware/Rootkit - don't install such a thing. Read some reviews about that app, it´s just horrible.

Answer (score 4):

Not without a rooted device (or uninstalling/freezing the other apps). If you have a rooted device, you can control each apps network access e.g. using a firewall app like [DroidWall](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.googlecode.droidwall.free) or even a more complex security solution like [LBE Privacy Guard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lbe.security.lite). Both would allow you to say which app(s) may access the network via Wifi and/or mobile network -- so you could even let them all work while connected to the free Wifi provided by the hotel.

If you are not rooted, but your device runs at least Android 4.x or higher, you could alternatively (temporarily) "freeze" (i.e. disable) all apps which should not use the internet.

Comment: Since DroidWall doesn't work on recent devices there is a fork of it called Android Firewall. Worked for me well.

Comment: There's also [AFWall+](http://www.appbrain.com/app/afwall-%28free%29/dev.ukanth.ufirewall), another fork of *DroidWall*.

Answer (score 0):

Turn on Data Saver in Android will stop apps from using data when in background.