# Block mobile internet access except portable hotspot without rooting my phone

Tags: rooting, wifi-hotspot, firewall

I've seen many articles and tried many applications like '[mobiwol](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/40924/block-apps-from-accessing-the-internet-on-android-device)' 'droidwall' 'avast antivirus' 'foxfi'.

**What my problem is that I've a very limited mobile data and I want to use it with my laptop with wireless/usb tethering without any android app accessing internet.**

I was thinking to block all android application to access internet and just allow portable hotspot to access mobile data, then I'll connect via portable hotspot and use the data in my laptop. I found application like 'droidwall' or 'avast antivirus' which requires a rooted device, but I cannot root my device as it'll void warranty.

Then I found 'Noroot firewall' or '[mobiwol](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/40924/block-apps-from-accessing-the-internet-on-android-device)' which creates a virtual VPN to block internet access. That's exactly what I want. But I want to allow portable hotspot to access mobile data which is not possible [see 2nd last answer here](http://www.mobiwol.com/faqs.html). So basically I'm struck.

Can anyone please suggest what should I do? or simply *how can I use internet in laptop via android device without android app accessing mobile data?*

Note: My device - samsung tab2 3100, android version 4.1.2

Answer (score 1):

- Go to `Settings`>`Data Usage`
- Check 'Restrict Background Data'

(It will prevent apps from using Data)