# Disable all but a few applications from accessing mobile data connections

Tags: mobile-data

I would like to disable all of the applications on my phone from accessing my mobile data connection, except for a select few applications that allow me to remotely control my phone, and thus, require a data connection. Is there any way to do this?

Im using an HTC One M8, running stock (non-rooted) Android 5 with HTC Sense 6.

Comment: You need a firewall. See my answer [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/107076/96277).