# Is Mobiwol incompatible with WiFi networks, e.g. my home network?

Tags: wi-fi, 5.1-lollipop, firewall

I recently installed Mobiwol, following [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/40926/153472), but now, my WiFi doesn't work. I haven't blocked any system apps from accessing the internet, but still, no WiFi. I looked at the [FAQ for Mobiwol](http://www.mobiwol.com/faqs.html), which states

> **Why Won't My WiFi HotSpot Work?**
>
> This is not a bug. WiFi tethering and WiFi hotspots are, unfortunately, not currently compatible with Mobiwol being enabled.

I might be unclear on the definition of a "WiFi hotspot," but my interpretation is that "when you have Mobiwol enabled, your phone cannot connect to WiFi," which doesn't seem correct. It's also strange because [Mobiwol's page in the Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.netspark.firewall) lists "Fixed WiFi and Firewall Loop issues ...", which makes it sound like WiFi should be working.

But, since my router and WiFi works on other devices, so it seems plausible that Mobiwol is the problem. If I disable it, the WiFi works.

Is Mobiwol incompatible with WiFi networks? Or does blocking something like the Google App prevent everything from connecting to WiFi?

Comment: Ok you are right, thats how that firewall works. So its not a problem with disabling Google apps or anything. You could try other alternative firewalls and see if the problem persists

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=inc.salzburg.company.easywall
I have created an app, which disables apsp without regard in which network you are in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The incompatibility of wi-fi and wi-fi tethering is due to the way most "no root firewalls" work.

> Sometimes this depends on the Android version in question because some
>   Android versions have a bug preventing tethering and the VPN service
>   working together.

Some devices hibernate Wi-Fi, preventing tethering from working when the screen is off and this behaviour can be disabled in the advanced Wi-Fi settings.

Currently as it stands, it seems Mobiwol firewall still has no compatibility with wi-fi or wifi-tethering in which case I would recommend installing an **alternative no root firewall** e.g [NetGuard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.faircode.netguard).

Netguard **has confirmed support** for wifi-tethering as mentioned here:

> *Can I tether / use Wi-Fi calling while using NetGuard?*
>
> Yes, but this needs to be enabled in NetGuard's settings. Whether or
>   not it works depends on your Android version because some Android
>   versions have a bug preventing tethering and the VPN service working
>   together.

You could also browse Izzy's F-droid repo with similar firewalls here: [Internet firewalls](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_admin_firewall#group_377) and choose the one suiting your needs.

Reference

- [NetGuard: FAQs](https://github.com/M66B/NetGuard/blob/master/FAQ.md)